# Ballpark Text Dimensions with Java FontMetrics

Tags: java, fonts

I'm currently drawing a string to a canvas with a specified font. I would, however, like to scale this font based on the window size.

Given a target string, how do I find the point size of a particular font face so that printing the target string will be either `h` units tall, or `w` units wide? Is there a linear relationship between point size and font dimensions?

I can think of very smelly ways to determine a relative point size (pick an arbitrary size and shrink / grow until the dimensions are within some epsilon of the target), but would rather do it more cleanly.

I want to do this with fonts-only, if possible, and not resort to affine transformations.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Need a way to scale a font to fit a rectangle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876234/need-a-way-to-scale-a-font-to-fit-a-rectangle)

Answer (score 3):

For the [best metrics](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5998117/230513), I prefer `TextLayout`, illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8282330/230513), but `deriveFont()`, suggested by @StanislavL among the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9311720/230513), is surprisingly agile and not at all malodorous.