# JavaFX font size from width

Tags: java, javafx, fonts

I want to calculate the Font Size due to a width value.

```
//Custom Font
Font.loadFont(Fonts.class.getResourceAsStream("/font/bignood/bignoodletoo.ttf"), 10)
String text = "Hello World";
Double width = 100;
```

[Similiar SO Question to Java AWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14380035/java-font-size-from-width)

[Similar SO Question to Java AWT 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876234/need-a-way-to-scale-a-font-to-fit-a-rectangle)

---

**Edit: Use case**

Think about a button that have a text `"PLAY MONEY"¹`.
Now I will translate the text to PT_BR and it calls now `"DINHEIRO FICTICIO"²`.
As you can see, the word² is bigger than word¹, so if you set the same `Font Size` then you gonna see `DINHEIRO FIC...` inside the button.

So the mission here is get the `width` value of the `Button`, get the `text` and apply the `Font Size` to fit the full text inside the `Button`, whenever I change the `text`.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific on what you want to get the width of (Like a Scene or something), and how large you want the font to be compared to it?

Comment: @Austin, the width I will get from button, label e etc.. Any object that have a text. The text with the custom font needs to fit the exactly width value.

Comment: The text needs to fit or the `Button` / `Label`? The latter 2 include margins for the text...

Comment: @fabian, the text needs to fit any width value. I will update the question with an use case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Below is a `findFontSizeThatCanFit()` method (and demo) that can be useful for this.

([See it in action online](http://rextester.com/NZG51913))

```
public class FxFontMetrics {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int maxWidth = 100;
        System.out.println("# Text -> Font size that can fit text under " + maxWidth + " pixels");
        Stream.of(
                "DINHEIRO FICTICIO",
                "Dinheiro ficticio",
                "PLAY MONEY",
                "Play money",
                "Devise factice qui compte pour du beurre")
                .forEach(text -> {
                    double size = findFontSizeThatCanFit(Font.font("dialog", 45), text, maxWidth);
                    System.out.println(text + " -> " + size);
                });
    }

    private static double findFontSizeThatCanFit(Font font, String s, int maxWidth) {
        double fontSize = font.getSize();
        double width = textWidth(font, s);
        if (width > maxWidth) {
            return fontSize * maxWidth / width;
        }
        return fontSize;
    }

    private static double textWidth(Font font, String s) {
        Text text = new Text(s);
        text.setFont(font);
        return text.getBoundsInLocal().getWidth();
    }
}
```

It prints:

```
# Text -> Font size that can fit text under 100 pixels
DINHEIRO FICTICIO -> 10.475703324808185
Dinheiro ficticio -> 12.757739986295396
PLAY MONEY -> 15.587183195068118
Play money -> 17.152428810720266
Devise factice qui compte pour du beurre -> 4.795354500327807
```

Comment: It works, but it is "too expansive for what it is" (as I have to create a new Font/text object at every iteration...). I was expecting something with `GraphicsContext` as used in the linked `SO question 1` for Java AWT.

Comment: Ah, yes, we can avoid the loop by using a division (if non-round values are not allowed or desired, use `Math.floor()`). I edited the answer. This still involves creation of a dummy `Text` node, but no need for new `Font` objects, right. But this is assuming the font renders a given text in a way that is proportional to its size, but I'm not sure it's always linear in reality :-/

Comment: You could use a `private static` `Text` object, inside `textWidth(...)`, instead of creating a new `Text` each call, right?